# Palaeontology and Palaeobotany

Tags: palaeontology

Could someone please clarify the roles and differences between palaeontology and palaeobotany. My textbook says the palaeobotanists study plant and animal fossils, but other sources say that this is incorrect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Paleontology** is the main scientific branch, which study fossils and prehistoric times.

- Paleozoology studies the fossils and biology of prehistoric animals.
- Paleobotany studies fossils and biology of prehistoric plants.
- Paleobiology studies the biology of prehistoric organisms.
- Paleoecology studies the prehistoric ecological systems and ecology.

In fact, putting the prefix "paleo-" turns every scientific branch of biology to a branch concentrating on this subject but in prehistoric times.

Comment: For the most part a Paleontologist will be willing to study whatever their fossil site produces. Which is why many scientists who are really "paleozoologists" just call themselves paleontologists.